# Iterate through all documents in a MongoDB collection and saving the data in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I thought this would be a straightforward task but what I am trying to do is go through all the documents (users) in my collection using a cursor and saving some data into a JS array or set about a specific field of the user or all of the data on that user. I am able to see each document printed on the console, but after looping through all the documents, my array is still empty when printed. Where am I going wrong and if there is an alternative approach please let me know.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Users = require('./models/user.model');

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex:true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB connection success");
})

let arr = [];
async function getRecords() {
    let cursor = Users.find({}).cursor();
    for (let doc = await cursor.next(); doc != null; doc = await cursor.next()) {
        arr.push(doc);     //does not work :(
        console.log(doc);  //this works
    }
}

getRecords();
console.log("ARRAY:",arr);  //prints []
```

Answer (score 2):

## Suggestion

Your code should read as such

```
let arr = [];

// This is an async function (returns a promise)
async function getRecords() {
    let docs = await Users.find({}).lean();
    arr = docs.filter((doc) => doc !== null); // As an example, however, enter appropriate condition for filter
    return arr;
}

// Call the async funtion
getRecords().then(docs => {
  console.log("ARRAY:", arr); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Grey, I tried it out and indeed there is data in arr. However is it possible to then console.log(arr) without calling getRecords over and over again? I'm looking to store this data in memory and having to access the Mongodb over the network constantly seems to be costly.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can store the result in memory, but you have to determine how best to do so, be it at the backend or frontend - each with its own approach.

Comment: @user6235442 Kindly upvote and accept the answer. It will help your reputation as well. :)